# Gulp Open isn't being declared

Tags: javascript, npm, gulp

Here is my `open.js` task:

```
import gulp from 'gulp';
import gulpOpen from 'gulp-open';

gulp.task('open', () => { // doesn't work with `function()` either.

  const options = {
    uri: 'localhost:2368'
  };

  gulp.src(__filename)
  .pipe(open(options));
});
```

This example is exactly the same as `gulp-open`'s examples [found here](https://github.com/stevelacy/gulp-open/blob/master/examples/gulpfile.js#L36).

The error I receive is `ReferenceError: open is not defined.`

I'm using ES6 imports within my `gulpfile.babel.js`.

Comment: Your issue is at `.pipe(open(options));`. I think you want that to be `.pipe(gulpOpen(options));`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Towards the end of the snippet that you posted, you're referencing the undeclared variable `open`. That's called a `ReferenceError` in JavaScript, hence the error message that you got. Instead of `open`, you imported the `gulp-open` package as `gulpOpen`, so you should instead use:

`gulp.src(__filename)
  .pipe(gulpOpen(options));`

Comment: It's times like these when a linter really comes in handy: it should tell you that you're using a variable before its declaration. My favorite is [ESLint](http://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/getting-started), but there's also [JSHint](http://jshint.com/docs/).